# Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/clearUsernameBinding' could not be found

Tags: wcf-security

hi i am tring to use this article for making my wcf service authenticate without SSL

http://webservices20.blogspot.in/2008/11/introducing-wcf-clearusernamebinding.html

but i am geting this error when i try to compile :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<extensions>
  <bindingExtensions>
    <add name="clearUsernameBinding" type="ClearUsernameCollectionElement, ClearUsernameBinding" />
  </bindingExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyValidator,App_Code"/>
      </serviceCredentials>

      <!--To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment-->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!--To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information-->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="SampleServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
        customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyUserNameValidator, App_Code" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="SampleServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="~/QuadraService/Service.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IService" bindingConfiguration="Binding1"/>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    <endpoint binding="clearUsernameBinding" bindingConfiguration="myClearUsernameBinding" contract="IService" />
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<bindings>

  <clearUsernameBinding>
    <binding name="myClearUsernameBinding"
 messageVersion="Soap12">
    </binding>
  </clearUsernameBinding>

  <wsHttpBinding>

    <binding name="Binding1">
      <!-- UsernameToken over Transport Security -->
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>



</bindings>
```

```
 Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 
Parser Error Message: Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/clearUsernameBinding' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.
```

please help

Comment: The error is actually pretty clear. Check your web.config/app.config or configuration code to make sure the WCF binding extension is configured correctly. It would help if you would put the config into your question.

Comment: @SixtoSaez thanks for reply i added the config code in the question.Now please check if you find any error in it .

Comment: i checked config file and problem is solved but now i am getting another error :- "An error occurred when verifying security for the message." when try to use service on client end

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are receiving the "An error occurred when verifying security for the message" exception because you have not manually modified the configuration file on the client.

The author states the following in the comments:

> As for the desktop application, the client needs to manually configure
>   clearUsernameBinding as done in the sample console application. The
>   reason is that the clearUsernameBinding dll is not part of .Net 3.5
>   and needs to be deployed on the client side.